# Windows API for accessing an iOS App's Documents directory from the desktop?

Tags: windows, ios, api, storage, itunes

Alright, I hope I can phrase this in a way that makes sense. If not, please comment and I'll try to make it clearer :)

Apps on iOS can expose their Documents directory to the user via iTunes. Interaction is very limited, and governed by iTunes.

Does iTunes provide a Windows API to access an App's Documents directory programmatically, for instance to store files there without user interaction?

Comment: Fairly sure this is a private API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, no public API exists for ordinary Win32 applications to access an iOS app's Documents directory. Bummer.